# IntelliJ is converting file name to lower case and build is failing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I cloned a maven project from git and this was the initial class structure under the src folder:

```
 src
  |-main
    |- java
       |-com.controller
         |- CommonController.java
```

Now, when I build this project, I don't understand how but the file name in which class is defined, changed to lower case and the folder structure is changing to below:

```
 src
  |-main
    |- java
       |-com.controller
         |-commoncontroller.java
            |- CommonController
```

and then IntelliJ throws this error since the file name has got changed:
`java: class CommonController is public, should be declared in a file named CommonController.java`

I searched a lot to find what is causing this but could not find any valid reason.

For other folks, this is not the case. So, I'm suspecting it's IntelliJ settings. Also, this issue is not for one codebase, I'm facing this problem with other projects as well. So thought to get it's root cause and fix it permanently.

Comment: Have you tried changing the file name back?

Comment: Yes, changing the file name back helps. It doesn't throw error then. However, there are multiple files in the project and all class' file name is lower cased. For simplicity, I gave one example in the question.

Comment: I would be really surprised if IntelliJ were doing this. Are you sure that it is IntelliJ and not something else? What's your operating system? Your file system? Do you have AV scanners installed? How do you build the project? Does the same also happen when you build via maven?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sounds like it might be this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows.  The problem would be that someone someone somewhere has done `git config --global core.ignorecase true` ... which you shouldn't do if you are working on Java projects.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't initially name it `commoncontroller` and then renamed it? Case insensitive file systems (the default mode for example for Windows' NTFS) sometimes consider renaming a file `commoncontroller.java` to `CommonController.java` a no-op and does nothing. Try renaming to a different intermediate file name.

Comment: @knittl, OS is windows. How i open the porject and run it is by importing the pom.xml file into IntelliJ and run either clicking "Run" button which eventually triggers the build first and another option i tried is ```mvn clean install```. Both ways I get my class file name changed

Comment: @StephenC, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it solved the problem.

Comment: @Akanksha_p and the file names are correct _before_ running the build? That's odd. And doesn't make any sense if the blog linked by Stephen was the solution.